# Printing a recursive array

Tags: json

can someone help me print the "text" value from this json decoded array?
i did echo $obj["text"] and i get a blank :(

ah, i did the var_dump ; it says its an array of 20 elements inside an array of 1 element :-)
so after editing the code 42 times i have come to the solution only because the awesome Fangel helped that to print text the following line needs to be placed:
echo $obj[0]["text"];

```
$obj=[
        {
          "created_at":"Mon Sep 03 05:00:30 +0000 2012",
          "id":242487207418544128,
          "id_str":"242487207418544128",
          "text":"Clint, come to the Democratic Convention. We'll get you a coherent speech to read - and we'll even help you comb your hair.",
          "source":"web",
          "truncated":false,
          "in_reply_to_status_id":null,
          "in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,
          "in_reply_to_user_id":null,
          "in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,
          "in_reply_to_screen_name":null,
          "user":{
             "id":15376626,
             "id_str":"15376626",
             "name":"BarrackObama",
             "screen_name":"BarrackObama",
             "location":"Washington, D.C.",
             "url":null,
             "description":"President of the United States of America",
             "protected":false,
             "followers_count":94289,
             "friends_count":1,
             "listed_count":577,
             "created_at":"Thu Jul 10 12:05:37 +0000 2008",
             "favourites_count":0,
             "utc_offset":-18000,
             "time_zone":"Quito",
             "geo_enabled":false,
             "verified":false,
             "statuses_count":106,
             "lang":"en",
             "contributors_enabled":false,
             "is_translator":false,
             "profile_background_color":"E6EB6F",
             "profile_background_image_url":"http://a0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/76798997/PresidentialSeal.jpg",
             "profile_background_image_url_https":"https://si0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/76798997/PresidentialSeal.jpg",
             "profile_background_tile":false,
             "profile_image_url":"http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/56441335/so_normal.jpg",
             "profile_image_url_https":"https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/56441335/so_normal.jpg",
             "profile_link_color":"0FA7FF",
             "profile_sidebar_border_color":"EAFF08",
             "profile_sidebar_fill_color":"171CA6",
             "profile_text_color":"E69407",
             "profile_use_background_image":true,
             "default_profile":false,
             "default_profile_image":false,
             "following":null,
             "follow_request_sent":null,
             "notifications":null
          },
          "geo":null,
          "coordinates":null,
          "place":null,
          "contributors":null,
          "retweet_count":110,
          "entities":{
             "hashtags":[

             ],
             "urls":[

             ],
             "user_mentions":[

             ]
          },
          "favorited":false,
          "retweeted":false
       }
    ]
```

Comment: It seems to have look at a binary file!

Comment: are you joking? i didnt get the joke? can u clarify?

Comment: I guess it is about formatting of your JSON.

Comment: You should understand we are not machines to read such badly formatted sentences. At the time of asking question, make sure that the question is easy to read. @FAngel Yep, it is about the formatting of his JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way to print it:`echo $obj[0]["text"];`

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

> assoc
>
> When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative
>   arrays.

When you set second parameter as true, you should do `echo $obj["text"];` instead of `$obj->text;` because, as it says in manual, second parameter, when true, force json_decode return associative arrays even if it is an object in JSON.

As far as I can see, you have an array of objects in your JSON. So after json decode you should have an array of objects also. Just use `foreach` loop to go through array and print text of all items:

```
foreach($obj as $item) {
    echo $item->text + "<br/>";
}
```

or like this for associative arrays(if second param of `json_decode` is true):

```
foreach($obj as $item) {
    echo $item["text"] + "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: okay i not completely solved the problem, could you help me to print the text from the object i posted in the edit

Comment: See updated answer. Suppose that is what you need. At least as I understand your question

Comment: yea i guess thats what i need, however i need to wait for 30 minutes to get the json as the url is down.

Comment: If you are not sure what is a structure of an object you are working with, you can use var_dump to see it on your page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: i did all that and what not o.o. this is just a part of the problem, now i have to put it in html page where the text "appears" (html display effect) long day ahead and i am already bored :(

Comment: thanks for the help . you cant even guess how much i appreciate it :D

Comment: Well... that is really basic! I guess you are really new to programming. Take any book about PHP and read it carefully. That is just advice. Just collect that in a variable. And than echo that variable where it should be. `foreach($obj as $item) {
    $collectedText .= $item["text"] + "<br/>";
}` and than something like this in place where you need it: `<?php echo $collectedText; ?>`